# CKEditor loads several times in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using the gem CKEditor on my platform.
The problem is that if I press the "Back" button of the browser and then the "Forward" Ckeditor loads twice (or N times if I do this N number of times).

I am using CKEditor only for one field:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :mail_message_hmtl_body, as: :ckeditor, id: "html_body" %>
```

And when doing the exercise that I explain it looks like this:

[image]

Any Idea?

Thanks!!!