# Browser back/forward button loads multiple CKEditor forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have a form for making a post in Rails 5. I am using the CKEditor text editor and it works fine. However, clicking the browser's forward or back button loads a new text editor each time stacked one on top of the other. For reference: I am using the CKEditor gem from "galetahub."
My problem is similar to this problem:
[CKEditor loads several times in Ruby on Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539979/ckeditor-loads-several-times-in-ruby-on-rails-5)

I think it is a problem with turbolinks, but I don't know what else to try. Short of disabling turbolinks altogether, I have tried:

1. Inserting "data-no-turbolink" and "data: { turbolinks: false }" on the div and form field.
2. I've tried the standard implementation from the gem into an "init_ckeditor" js file:

   ```
   ready = ->
     $('.ckeditor').each ->
       CKEDITOR.replace $(this).attr('id')

   $(document).ready(ready)
   $(document).on('page:load', ready)
   ```
3. And variations of:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function() 
   {
     CKEDITOR.replace('text_form')
   });

   and

   $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
     CKEDITOR.replace('text_form')
   });
   (Both separately and together.)
   ```

Here is the gem:

```
    gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
```

Here is the form and field:

```
    <%= form_with model: @article, local: true, html:{multipart: true} do |form| %>

      <div class="text-form">
        <%= form.cktext_area :text, class: 'ckeditor', id: 'text_form' %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

Here is the js:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('text_form')
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Been looking for answers to this for a long time. Ordinarily, I've been able to troubleshoot things myself, but this has me racking my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Get the CK editor length on load. 
Then add when length is 0
if(CKEDITOR.Instances['text_form']==null) CKEDITOR.replace('text_form')

Comment: This didn’t work for me. Do I need to wrap this method with $(document).ready... or something similar.